# Преобразовать char из dw в db

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

В куче у меня лежит массив:

```
006166F4  6A 00 6F 00 70 00   j.o.p.
```

Мне нужно преобразовать его в `6A 6F 70`
Я вижу решение - пройтись циклом и положить измененные значения в новый массив. Возможно есть более красивый способ?

Comment: Похоже, что у вас там просто лежит строка в UTF16. Считайте ее и преобразуйте штатными методами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет другого способа. Но нужно подумать, а стоит ли это делать? Если массив будет передаваться куда-то наружу, то необходимо, конечно. Если же он будет использоваться только внутри, то в месте использования нужно просто извлекать каждый второй байт